# Google simultaneous connections

Tags: sockets, gmail, imap

Does Google cap the number of connections a server can make to Google IMAP servers?  I'm looking for overall limit rather than per account limit (which is 10 connections by the way).  Does anyone have an experience with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a cap indeed, but I'm not sure how many sockets it is, nor if it is documented.

See [here](http://www.thamtech.com/blog/2008/03/29/gmail-to-google-apps-email-migration/) for information, or look for imapsync forums, where people complains about it.